# Client misunderstanding nmap

Tags: network, vulnerability-scanners, network-scanners, ports, nmap

My client wants their public facing IP addresses to be secure, but thinks that running nmap port scans will draw attention from hackers.

To settle this once and for all, what do you say?

Comment: How exactly your client argue that "running nmap port scans will draw attention from hackers" ?

Comment: He thinks somehow the nmap scans will be detected and then make his network a target for hackers.

Comment: Tell him if he doesn't do the port scan, hackers will do it for him. Better knowing the result and patch than waiting for them to use their findings.

Comment: It won't draw attention because the hackers can't see the nmap traffic (or rather, if they can then you have more important things to worry about probably). It also sounds like your client doesn't trust your advice on this if this is what you're telling him and you may need to think about improving his confidence in your experience.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I say put up an IDS and/or enable firewall logging capable of detecting port scans.

Wait for one to happen naturally, and then show the client the evidence that they're *already* being port-scanned.

Alternately, you can simply schedule some downtime, unplug the WAN interface from the Internet, plug it into a standalone local router that pretends to be the Internet, and run the portscan; physically invisible from the Internet.

Answer (score 2):

It all comes down to properly inform your client. You got hired for a reason, it's your job to explain your client this will not attract hackers.

What's your scope? Isn't this stated in your statement of work (SOW)?

Explain to them that if they want their public facing assets to be secure, an nmap scan is one step of the many ways to determine the level of security and if this is not possible, a proper assessment can't be done.

Quite honestly, it sounds a little scary that you are not able to convince a client to allow you to do this, unless it is not properly stated in the SOW.

In addition, if the client still don't want you to perform this scan, state this clearly in your report. This way everything is covered from your end.